# Consulta con multi left join, MARIADB

Tags: mariadb

Quiero realizar una consulta con algunos left join. Para poder explicar bien la explicacion necesito describir las tablas:

**Tabla productos:**

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `balanzaid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `proveedor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `especial` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`),
    INDEX `ultimamodificacion` (`ultimamodificacion`),
    INDEX `id2` (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre_2` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;
```

**Tabla tipo de productos:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tipodeproducto` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `unidaddemedida` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `unidadabreviado` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tipo de ticket de productos:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ticketproductos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `notadecreditoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idrubro` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `productoid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `precio` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `porpeso` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `promocionid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `preciooriginal` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pesodeprecio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_2` (`id`),
    INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `idrubro` (`idrubro`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `productoid` (`productoid`),
    INDEX `anulado` (`anulado`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;
```

**Tabla de Tickets**

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `anulacion` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `total` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `descuento` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `terminal` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `senacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `devolucion` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `formasdepago` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `señacliente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `anulacion` (`anulacion`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

Y la relacion de las tablas seria asi:

`ticket productos` son los productos de los ticket de la tabla `tickets`, `tickets.id <-> ticketproductos.idticket`,

los productos estan relacionados de la tabla `ticketproductos` y `productos` asi: `productos.id <-> ticketproductos.productoid`

y los productos existen varios tipos de la cual esta relacionado de la siguiente manera : `productos.tipodeproducto <-> ticketproductos.id`

Resumen, estas son las relaciones:

- productos.tipodeproducto<->ticketproductos.id
- productos.id<->ticketproductos.productoid
- tickets.id<->ticketproductos.idticket
- productos.id<->ticketproductos.productoid

y la consulta a cuestionar es la siguiente:

```
Select 
IFNULL(rubros.nombre, '') As nombrerubro  
,IFNULL(productos.nombre,'') As nombre, 
ticketproductos.productoid AS productoid
, ticketproductos.ticketid, 
ticketproductos.cantidad AS cantidad, 
ticketproductos.precio AS precio, 
ticketproductos.idrubro AS idrubro, ticketproductos.porpeso AS porpeso
, ticketproductos.pesodeprecio AS pesodeprecio, 
IFNULL(tipodeproducto.unidadabreviado,'') As unidad,
 ticketproductos.precio2 As precioespecial, ticketproductos.promocionid, 
ticketproductos.notadecreditoid 
FROM 
ticketproductos 
LEFT JOIN (tipodeproducto, productos) ON ((productos.id = ticketproductos.productoid) 
AND (tipodeproducto.id = productos.tipodeproducto OR productos.tipodeproducto = 0)) 
LEFT JOIN rubros ON rubros.id = ticketproductos.idrubro 
WHERE ticketproductos.ticketid = 1 AND ticketproductos.anulado = false;
```

Los nombres de los productos los entrega `""` es decir nada,  porque los resultados son NULL. Los resultados siempre figuran NULL, ¿me podrian ayudar por favor? Porque los LEFT JOIN creo que estan mal ingresados. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Primero usa la tabla de la cual obtienes mas datos, que en este caso es `ticketproductos` luego vas haciendo los `LEFT JOIN` con las tablas consiguientes:

```
SELECT    Ifnull(rubros.nombre, '')   AS nombrerubro , 
          Ifnull(productos.nombre,'') AS nombre, 
          ticketproductos.productoid  AS productoid , 
          ticketproductos.ticketid, 
          ticketproductos.cantidad                  AS cantidad, 
          ticketproductos.precio                    AS precio, 
          ticketproductos.idrubro                   AS idrubro, 
          ticketproductos.porpeso                   AS porpeso , 
          ticketproductos.pesodeprecio              AS pesodeprecio, 
          Ifnull(tipodeproducto.unidadabreviado,'') AS unidad, 
          ticketproductos.precio2                   AS precioespecial, 
          ticketproductos.promocionid, 
          ticketproductos.notadecreditoid 
FROM      ticketproductos 
LEFT JOIN productos ON productos.id = ticketproductos.productoid AND productos.tipodeproducto = ticketproductos.id
LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.id = ticketproductos.idticket
LEFT JOIN rubros ON rubros.id = ticketproductos.idrubro 
WHERE     ticketproductos.ticketid = 1 
AND       ticketproductos.anulado = false;
```

En dado caso que este no te obtenga los valores que quieres, intenta ir creando el query por partes por ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticketproductos 
LEFT JOIN productos ON productos.id = ticketproductos.productoid
```

Si este te trae el dato que necesitas le vas agregando las otras tablas y las otras condiciones, si por ejemplo la consulta anterior funciona, puedes agregar la siguiente tabla ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM      ticketproductos 
LEFT JOIN productos ON productos.id = ticketproductos.productoid AND productos.tipodeproducto = ticketproductos.id
LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.id = ticketproductos.idticket
```

y así sucesivamente

Comment: Es una posible solución pero sería más lenta los consulta, lo que me gustaría es que no hayan subsqueries, así sería más optima

Comment: Si, por eso, no harias ningun subquery, solo estarias revisando que cada LEFT JOIN que haces funcione correctamente